# Error when growing system partition with LiveUSB

Tags: partitioning

I was trying to grow my Ubuntu partition, first moving it and then growing. But it throws me the error on the picture. Don't know what to do now. Tell me if you need more info and I will provide it.[KDE Partition manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMsdG.png)

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL3Dy.png)

Here is the complete log https://pastebin.com/034SUeLt

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Are you booted to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB when trying to resize? Why only increase it 10G?

Comment: I was using a LiveUSB of Lubuntu 20.04 to do the task on a Ubuntu 20.04. I wanted to increase it because I wasn't reading well and thought that I've got left only 17GiB when those were the GiB used lol

Comment: Try to do it in 2 stages. First move the partition to the left, click ```apply changes```. Then try to grow it. So we know what gives the error. The moving or the growing.